# Dropdownlist with auto-complete using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a dropdown list with auto-complete using twitter-bootstrap type-ahead.

Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Could you give us more information, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is pretty easy actually, you need a `<datalist>` and an `<input>`:

```html
<datalist id="myList">
  <option value="Just">
  <option value="google">
  <option value="it">
  <option value="you">
  <option value="lazy">
  <option value="duck">
</datalist>

<input type="text" placeholder="type here..." list="myList" autofocus>
```

This is it. The `auto-complete` shouldn't require anything else. 
This is basic HTML, no Bootstrap required.